# Text browser friendly SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, browser-support

I was wondering if this exists/feasible. I'm talking about a stripped down version of the website for browsers such as links.

The need is practical from my point. Sometimes I need to work with no graphical environment (whether changing it/fixing it/it crashed and I **really** don't want to restart) and since I'm not a walking dictionary of UNIX usually with a quick search SO gives me the small things I need.

The thing is, the plethora of scripts and links make it hard to see the question and answer - possible but a bit difficult. I'm thinking something closer in spirit to the phone APP in terms of what should be on screen.

**EDIT**

I saw the linked questions, the second is specifically very close, but I think support in this context should be a read only site, with questions followed by answers, perhaps with only a search feature as far as menus go.

Comment: MSE related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277392/to-what-extent-is-se-usable-with-console-browser-not-supporting-javascript-and  and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31069/browsing-using-lynx-and-links-text-only-browser

Comment: Stripped down? No problem. `ctrl` + `p`

Comment: @Ihazkode Print? Pretty sure that would still show all the extra stuff I want stripped (on paper, but still).

Comment: There's really very little left in there https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnstn.png

Comment: @Ihazkode That's actually not bad. How did you produce that specifically? I'm guessing it's browser dependent. Maybe post as an answer.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 60 and all I did was press `ctrl` + `p` and that's what I get.

Comment: @Ihazkode On firefox print to file worked. I'll check if I can do something similar in Links, good advice, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=votes&q=text%20browser) can help you in this case...

In fact, [Column 80](https://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-stack-exchange) by [Mark Henderson](https://stackapps.com/users/816/mark-henderson) seems to be the best for your requirement.

Link: http://www.column80.com/

> [image]
>
> <sub>Image taken from its StackApps entry</sub>

Answer (score 7):

So you have one machine, with which you fiddle so much that your graphical subsystem sometimes goes belly up, and you don't want to restart that machine to recover the graphical mode.

You don't have another device on which you can browse the web to find solutions for the results of your fiddling, so you want to be able read Stack Exchange sites in text mode?

In my opinion Stack Overflow shouldn't spend developer time on that while more pressing matters exist.

Comment: If you say so (whatever "pressing" means in this context).

Comment: @kabanus it means that there are way, way more important issues that a lot of people can benefit from when they are addressed, as opposed to this very niche problem.

Comment: They have these little handheld computers now, which you can use to browse the web. Amazing things, really. If you're frequently b0rking your main computer, you might get one. Or, you know, you might have one already...

Comment: Checkout the other answer, apparently there is already a nice solution - this is a utility thing, it may be faster/easier for some people than another machine.  Also @CodyGray, [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), though no harm done.

Comment: In what way did my comment violate the "be nice" policy, @kabanus?

Comment: @CodyGray Not to go off discussion, but I was getting a rude vibe. If I'm reading too much into it, than drop it, I apologize for assuming.