# Text-based browser support

Tags: discussion, browser-support

[Text-browsers such as Lynx, Links, ELinks are not supported by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161). The policy goes:

> We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use. This does not include beta/dev releases, which are not supported.

On a daily basis, I'm working on an X-term free system and would find it handy to quickly browse/search Stack Overflow. To my big surprise, the site's text-based version looks very chaotic (see image below). This was a surprise as I can imagine that a small, but not insignificant, subgroup of the Stack Overflow/Server Fault/Super User community could benefit from text-based support.

The referenced question/answer above states that they support the browsers the vast majority uses. This seems to imply that text-based browsing can never be supported since it is already not supported now. Hence, if a user wants to give it a try, he might quickly give up. And hence, the text-based browser count will never go up never entering the realm of majority browsers.

**Question:** Would it not be possible to at least do a minor cleanup of the Stack Overflow site to fill in the missing gaps to improve the text-based browsing experience. Not everything needs to work, but an easy browsing/searching would be nice.

**Note:** I posted this here as I do not believe that the overall Stack Exchange community is waiting for lynx support (i.e. the community who is not Unix/Linux minded).

I just found a reference to http://www.column80.com/ thanks to the question: *[Text browser friendly SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355761)*. Sadly, I was unable to find this question earlier as I could not browse Stack Overflow with my text-browser. Another site I just found via *[Mobile optimized version of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896)* was http://stackmobile.com. This also shows a very clean text-based version.

**Suggestion:** Detect the browser and forward to or suggest the usage of any of the above alternative sites. This might already be handy.

---

[image]

As you notice in the image above:

- There is a list of 7 with only item 6 having some words:
- Searching Stack Overflow is indicated by the word "BUTTON"
- Trying to *Log In*, fails
- There is a new business plan for private Q & A

Comment: Hmm... what does [unix.se] look like? :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey identical

Comment: Would it be easier to use the [Stackoverflow api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and just curl what you want? Seems like it'd be easier for browsing/fetching related tasks. Posting back would probably be a bit more challenging

Comment: It should also be noted that making a site useable in textmode non-js browsers also tends to improve the sites useability for blind users. And trust me, theres a lot of those folks out there, and they all surf the web.

Comment: @Shayne that's an excellent point and you managed to make it before me. I was going to point out SE's dedication to including users rather than excluding them. I've not actually tried how the sites behave for the visually impaired but if there is going to be an improvement, that's a strong argument to support text browsers.

Comment: @Shayne that's a great point. Stackexchange is trying to be welcoming to minorities, and blind people are minorities, too. And, guess what? To be welcoming to them, you don't even need to engage the community: Merely improving the structure of your pages to be more accessible is already a great start.

Comment: I think @RichS makes a good point. The API is accessible, why not just make a cli client? You can solve a lot of problems by going with something that's already designed to be used at the prompt.

Comment: Also, I just stumbled on this (I hope it's helpful): A few years back, some nice folks have made a good handful of [API clients](https://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-api-client-libraries-grouped-by-programming-language). I'm not entirely sure what the state is of each of those.

Comment: This isn't the first time when poor page composition made SO less accessible: it also used to make Bing [generate incorrect search snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371517/).

Comment: As a web dev I always try and make a point of making sure my pages work in Lynx and Links, simply because its a pretty immediate way of knowing if your site needs more work to be accessible. And theres good commercial reasoning. Some 10% give or take are visually impaired in some relatively serious way. If your website wants to make a million dollars a week (for instance) thats like leaving $100K on the table.

Comment: @Shane, I've raised a [question/discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358372/365141) 
 on SE Meta in the hope to have an idea of what can be done for the visually impaired.

Answer (score 18):

> Would it not be possible to at least do a minor cleanup of the StackOverflow site to fill in the missing gaps to improve the text-based browsing experience.

What you call "minor cleanup" appears to me as a major task. Only based on what you see in your screenshot the analysis looks grim.

- the `<ol>` list of 7 `<li>` items is

  - your usercard, with badges (had you been able to login)
  - your inbox
  - your achievements
  - help button
  - site switcher
  - sign up / login
  - the site switcher dialog

The "minor" clean-up would either need text to be added inside all these items, either on detection of the browser or it needs to be removed for non-text browser, for example by javascript. That would increase the network payload a bit, puts pressure on performance and that makes [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) unhappy.

The  `<button>` in the search form suffers from the same problem. It misses a textContent. This is what it would look like for all of us, if it was added:

[image: search added]

I admit that one might work.

That login fails needs more reproduction steps. What type of account did you use?

The new announcement dialog is hidden by css. I don't know any minor clean-ups that can solve this for both text-browser users and would still appeal to the majority of users with graphical browser. I rather expect the whole dialog handling and insertion in the DOM would need to be done differently.

I'm pretty sure Stack Overflow doesn't want to redirect their users to a third party by means of their software, automatically or by a banner. The target group of users is too small, the benefit low and the investment high, even if kept to a minor clean-up.

I won't expect text based browser support anywhere near the 6 to 8 weeks timeline.

Comment: I suspect this answer is entirely true, but I lament the reality. Whatever happened to the semantic web? It’s disappointing to see Stack Overflow using such abysmally poor web design practices. Javascript and CSS for *enhancements* is one thing, but when the text isn’t even readable, you’ve utterly failed. lite.cnn.com and text.npr.org are examples of doing it right. Much more encouraging than script kiddies pasting together a mess of CSS and Javascript without any eye on the big picture.

Comment: @CodyGray: "*Whatever happened to the semantic web?*" Javascript happened to it. Once that appeared, you could do things like present information out of order, hide panels, and so forth. Your site's appearance was no longer enslaved to the textual information you were presenting. Stack Overflow is not a website; it's a WebApp.

Comment: @Nicol Javascript making that *possible* did not make it *necessary*. It's entirely possible to use Javascript in conjunction with well-ordered HTML. It might not look as pretty without the Javascript running, but the information is still there. You can hide portions of it using Javascript without destroying semantics. I don't know why you'd want to display things out of order; that seems like a hack for not having them in the right order in the HTML in the first place. Even non-web applications need to degrade gracefully in limited environments. The same should be true for the web.

Comment: _That login fails needs more reproduction steps. What type of account did you use?_: I make use of google login, but I don't even hit that step. Entering the login-page just returns me to the start page. Not really what I expect.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with your sentiment and I know you were stating more of a hypothetical question, but the sad reality is, accommodating for that would only create more unnecessary work and issues for next to no pay-off

Comment: The funny thing is, some of those text only / lite pages are far easier to browse and read on a smartphone than pages that try to hide things or stretch and fit themselves onto my screen... I have a far easier time reading raw diffs than trying to read Gitlab's diffs with ~30 characters per line after all of the UI padding is done. I've always been fine with zooming in / scrolling, and the builtin "find on page" function is fine for gigantic pages. IMO if anything the textual information is "enslaved" to the webapp, not the other way around.

Comment: You don't need to use JS / browser detection for text-based browser only text. Consider Bootstrap's class for screen readers `.sr-only` for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758620/4027341

Comment: This answer misses one of the important things in the question IMO, which is that it rightfully points that the statement "We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use." is not logical or slightly irrational. Unsupported browsers can never become used by the "the vast majority". Supported browsers are then chosen by design, not by use. I bet when -insert top company name here- brutally try to impose a new browser where SO would crash, SO team would quickly set up work teams even if users wouldn't use it as a "majority" yet.

Comment: @Kaddath I agree, this leads to circular reasoning here: people can't use text browsers -> people don't use text browsers -> text browsers will not be supported -> people can't use text browsers... I do have to agree that text browser usage is indeed among the minority on the Internet, so even with support it's unlikely they'd get a ton more traffic from that. In a lot of cases, that might be a good reason to not support text browsers but it seems the technology and inclusivity focused SE network shouldn't.

Comment: I've had to browse with lynx for some *nix information in the past, I don't want to suddenly be unable to in the future. It would be a bit like an organisation for the blind deciding to eventually stop supporting the use of visual impairment software on their site.

Comment: @CodyGray Actually the surveillance web, funded by the advertisting and media industries, happened to it. The need to monitor and control the user experience, to manipulate users and to segment content to reinforce monopolies are not compatible with an open internet.

Comment: It's not that bad, a lot of it is naming buttons

Comment: "The minor clean-up would either need text to be added inside all these items, either on detection of the browser or it needs to be removed for non-text browser" — there is another option: stop using `<li>` tag where it does not belong. This will let you drop a bunch of ugly CSS rules, required to make `<li>` behave more like `<span>`. As many people I have seen that practice somewhere in the past and was initially impressed by it being so "stylistic" and "semantic". But now it feels more like a poor attempt at showing off.

Answer (score 8):

[Column 80](https://column80.com) supports Lynx.

It *would* be good if we had a [Skip Navigation link](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#skipnavlinks), though; I assumed that there was one, but apparently not.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: isn't a link to the original SO page required by the SO license?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It's required by SO the company, but not by the license. However, that hinders the usability of Column 80. Considering that it provides the usernames of the question askers and the question ids of the questions, and the site name is always present in the URL, I think it probably falls under the banner of "good faith effort to attribute the content". This is not an ordinary web page.